# npm run not giving scripts as suggestion

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I had to setup my dev machine from scratch due to some issues and in doing so, I also upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

I installed the latest node and npm, but I observe a strange behavior. When I press tab after typing the command

```
 npm run sta
```

I am not getting any suggestions/autocomplete on the terminal. In the example above, I would expect it to autocomplete to

```
npm run start
```

I have defined many scripts within the package.json, but none of those show up as suggestions or autocomplete, on pressing tab. E.g. within my scripts I have defined, `pack-linux-x64, pack-darwin-x64` etc. but on typing

```
npm run pack
```

and pressing tab, I am not getting the suggestions from what I have defined within the scripts of my package.json. Strangely, I get

```
npm run package.json
```

as the suggestion when I press tab.

This, of course, was not the behavior in my previous system.

If I type the command myself,e.g. `npm run pack-linux-x64` then it runs without any issues.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392200/npm-completion-broken)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[npm-completion - Tab Completion for npm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/npm-completion.1.html)

Enables tab-completion in all npm commands.

The  synopsis  above  loads  the  completions  into  your current shell. Adding it to your
       ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc will make the completions available everywhere:

```
       npm completion >> ~/.bashrc
       npm completion >> ~/.zshrc
```

You  may  of  course  also  pipe  the  output  of  npm  completion  to  a  file  such   as /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/npm  if  you  have  a system that will read that file for you.

When COMP_CWORD, COMP_LINE, and COMP_POINT are defined in the environment, npm  completion acts in "plumbing mode", and outputs completions based on the arguments.